# Using Explicit App ID For Initial Release

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Will soon upload my App for review on AppStore. However I am not using any App Services so I could use a Wildcard App ID.

But for future releases/patches I know I want to add Game Center Service so I would need an Explicit App ID for that.

Can I provide an Explicit App ID for my initial release even if I am not using any services to skip any future hassle for future releases when I do need App Services? What I am worried about is if the App would get rejected because of that.

Comment: I'm not aware of any case where being more specific caused issues, but let's see if anyone has any feedback... Is there something in the documentation that makes you wary of submitting the way you think is best since you get the option to choose the ID?

Comment: Not necessarily - However if I am using an Explicit App ID some App services are preselected (And can't be unselected) like Game Center.  If I am not using any Services, like Game Center, will Apple frown upon that during the review?

Comment: I think you are just setting up a unique ID for the app in case you use it any of the services that need to send push notifications or let Apple's databases be prepared to handle game center data for your app. Maybe put that screen shot in the question hi lighting what you are "forced" to accept would help? I'd hate to mis-understand where you are entering data and brush off a specific thing for you to think about.